# How to make the table responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm pretty new to this, was hoping someone could tell me how to make this table responsive. I'm using Bootstrap v 3.3.4 HTML5 and CSS3

Everything else is responsive just this table isn't

```
<style type="text/css">

.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border:none;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:1px 10px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:roboto, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;padding:1px 10px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yfiy{font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;vertical-align:bottom}
.tg .tg-qv16{font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-k010{font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-qnmb{font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;text-align:center}

</style>

<table align="center" class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 563px">

<colgroup>
<col style="width: 166px">
<col style="width: 81px">
<col style="width: 79px">
<col style="width: 86px">
<col style="width: 85px">
<col style="width: 66px">
</colgroup>
<tr>
<th class="tg-yfiy">test</th>
<th class="tg-k010">one</th>
<th class="tg-qv16">two</th>
<th class="tg-qv16">three</th>
<th class="tg-qv16">four</th>
<th class="tg-qv16">five</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
<td class="tg-qnmb">one</td>
<td class="tg-qv16">two</td>
<td class="tg-qv16">three</td>
<td class="tg-qv16">four</td>
<td class="tg-qv16">five</td>
</tr>
</table>  


</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: SO is not the proper venue for "please make this work for me." Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want help on how to properly ask questions.

Comment: You use bootstrap or not ? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap you need add the proper element and class ..

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        ...
    </table>
 </div>
```

and avoid styling size and inline

Answer (score 0):

yeah with boostrap as say scaisEdge, if you want more styles and customize you can consult the documentation [Boostrap tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) good luck.